# Change Ipad setting back from do nothing in nautilus

Tags: ipad

It use to open file explorer (nautilus) when I plugged it in. I messed up and set it to "do nothing". Now it won't see it at all, and my virtual box can't see it either. Where is the setting so I can change it back to ask? I went to settings>detail, but I didn't see it in removable devices. Any help would be great. I'm on 12.10 Ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't see it listed in settings>detail?  Under any of the options?  If not I don't know either.  That is the only place I know to look.